# De que forma guardar imagenes para website?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3

cuál es la mejor manera de almacenar y utilizar 40 fotos en producción? He estado investigando opciones como S3, BD o una carpeta estática (que es lo que estoy usando actualmente), pero no estoy seguro si esto será adecuado para su uso en producción.

Comment: Para esa pequeña cantidad cualquier cosa te sirve (aunque también influye el tamaño)